# How to show the path to in PhpStorm?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm

In my test application, there is the `EntryEditor` component in the App.vue.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import EntryEditor from "./components/EntryEditor.vue";
import { reactive } from "vue";
import type Entry from "@/types/Entry";
const doSomething = (entry: Entry) => {
  console.log(entry);
};
</script>

<template>
<main class="container m-auto p-10">
<TheHeader />
<EntryEditor @@create="doSomething" />
</main>
</template>
```

The EntryEditor:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import type Entry from "@/types/Entry";

const text = ref("");
const emoji = ref<Emoji | null>(null);
const maxChars = 280;

defineEmits<{
(e: "@create", entry: Entry): void;
}>();
</script>

<template>
<form
class="entry-form"
@submit.prevent="
  $emit('@create', {
    body: text,
    emoji,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    userId: 1,
    id: Math.random(),
  })
"
>
<EmojiField v-model="emoji" />
<div class="entry-form-footer">
  <span>{{ charCount }} / {{ maxChars }}</span>
  <button>
    Remember
    <ArrowCircleRight width="20" />
  </button>
</div>
</form>
</template>
```

If I try to find the way on `@@create` there is the following message:

[image]

Where can I enable the tool which helps to find the way?

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported, please follow the [WEB-52121](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52121/Vue-Provide-completion-for-custom-component-events) for updates